# SIGBUS error when compiling C short-program

Tags: arrays, c, char

I am trying to print a simple bill using C programming language but my code is not running when I compile it in windows. When I run it using Ubuntu I am getting an output but the values are distorted.
I tried running the code using an online debugger and it says "SIGBUS error at line 20".
Can anyone please help me sort this out?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

    int entries,i;
    char code[entries][10];
    int qty[entries];
    char name[20];
    float price[entries];
    float linetotal[entries];
    float subtotal[entries];

    printf("Enter the customer name : ");
    scanf("%s", name);

    printf("Enter the number of entries\n");
    scanf("%d",&entries);

   for(i=0;i<entries;i++)
   {
    printf("Enter the entry %d\n",i+1);
    printf("Enter the code: ");
    scanf("%s",code[i]);

    printf("Enter the quantity: ");
    scanf("%d",&qty[i]);

    printf("Enter the unit price: ");
    scanf("%f",&price[i]);
   }
//calculating line totals and subtotals
  linetotal[i] = qty[i]*price[i];
  printf("\n");

  printf("Maddy's printShop -Bokks to change the world\n");
  printf("\t\tInvoice\t\t\t\n");

  printf("Customer Name : %s\n", name);
  printf("----------------------------------------------\n");
  printf("Code \t\t Qty\t\t Unit Price\t\t Line Total\t\t\n");
  printf("-------------------------------------------------\n");
  for(i=0;i<entries;i++)
  {
  printf("%s\t\t%d\t\t%.2f\t\t%.2f\t\t\n",code[i],qty[i],price[i],linetotal[i]);
  }
  }
```

Comment: You cannot declare code[entries] until you have a value for entries. When you enter main(), entries has no defined value, so you'll get undefined behaviour. You need to allocate those variables with malloc().

Comment: you're using `entries` before initialising it, when declaring a variable in C it always has garbage values in it(values that happened to be in memory), one way to fix it is to `scanf` a value into entries at the start of the program.

Comment: @LSerni okay,Thank you so much